# Как записать юзера при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть две кнопки в лабе и не в лабе мне нужно что бы при нажатии этих кнопок записывал кто в лабе и кто нет, а при нажатии `кто в лабе` выводил кто там.
Код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('hide')
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
 
    # Создание кнопок и приветствие
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Кто в лабе")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("подтвердить")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton(" Разработчики ")
 
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, помогу тебе ворваться в лабу!".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
 

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'подтвердить':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ты в лабе⚡",callback_data='1')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ты не в лабе⚡", callback_data='2')

 
            markup.add(item1, item2)
 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать,\n ты в лабе или нет")', reply_markup=markup)

        elif message.text == " Информация ":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "  Мы работаем в сфере создания треков уже 4 года." +
                " Наша профессиональная команда готова помочь вам с любыми музыкальными трудностями, мы обладаем лучшей аппаратурой для выполнений всех" + 
                " задач в сфере музыкального продюсирования. Наши услуги дают возможность максимально индивидуализировать продукт под себя.")

        elif message.text == " Разработчики ":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Данный бот был разработан <b>LimeGeeg Corporation™️</b> & <b>Cat️</b>, || <b>YouTube: LimeGeeg️</b>', parse_mode='html')


        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'По другим вопросам пишите сюда → @Seapix')



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:

            # keyboard (Работа с кнопками под текстом)
            if call.data == '1':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Пишите сюда → @Seapix')
            elif call.data == '2':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Пишите сюда → @Seapix')
            elif call.data == '3':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Пишите сюда → @Seapix')
            elif call.data == '4':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Пишите сюда → @Seapix')
 
            # remove inline buttons
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Спасибо! ",
                reply_markup=None,)

            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="Пишите, всегда поможем!")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Что такое `лаба`? И что конкретно вы от нас хотите?

Comment: лаба это лаборатория

Comment: лаборатория нажми кнопочку подтвердить Там выскакивает этот 2 ты в ней да или нет Если другой  другой человек захочет узнать кто там находится он жмет кнопку кто в лабе вот и все

Comment: Короче вы просто хотите по нажатии на кнопку записать юзера в список участников этой "лаборатории"?

Comment: вы хотите чтобы это работало для какого-то конкретного чата или все взаимодействуют с ботом исключительно через ЛС?

Comment: да а если его нет то удалять

Comment: Что удалять?___

Comment: пойдем в дискорд долго писать

Comment: это вам не фриланс, вы либо нормально формулируете вопрос/проблему или не задаёте его вовсе.

Comment: судь в том что все в лс а если кто- то хочет узнать кто там то это тоже лс

Comment: там все в лс работает в лс а данные передаются между собой

Comment: ответ на Что удалять?___ –   удалять пользователя если его нет(нажал на кнопку )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй

```
# так как у тебя нет бд обойдемся словарем
# ПыСы. при перезапуске бота данные пропадут. 
# Ты либо их записывай в файл либо переходи на aiogram
users = {}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message: types.Message):
    # при нажатии на старт, сделаем запись юзера в нашу "бд"
    # PS если юзер нажмет ещё раз, то ничего не произойдет (если юзер записан в бд)
    users.setdefault(message.from_user.id, {"in_lab": None})

    # не делайте так. Вы не закрываете файл, могут быть тупые ошибки.
    # sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    # делайте так
    with open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb') as sticker:
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sticker=sticker)

    # Создание кнопок и приветствие
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    # рекомендую сократить код с этого
    # item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Кто в лабе")
    # item2 = types.KeyboardButton("подтвердить")
    # item3 = types.KeyboardButton(" Разработчики ")
    # markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
    # до такого
    markup.add("Кто в лабе", "Подтвердить", " Разработчики ")
    # забудьте про format, юзайе f-строки
    # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>,
    # помогу тебе ворваться в лабу!".format( message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    # parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text=f"Добро пожаловать, {message.from_user.first_name}!\n"
                          f"Я - <b>{bot.get_me().first_name}</b>, помогу тебе ворваться в лабу!",
                     parse_mode='html',
                     reply_markup=markup)


# прекратите так делать. Делайте для каждой команды отдельный хендлер
# @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
# PS также смысла писать content_types=['text'] нет, так как это значение по-умолчанию
# и уберите это условие в фильтр декоратора так ведь лучше
# if message.chat.type == 'private':
# а все свои if message.text == '...': также запихните в фильтр декоратора
@bot.message_handler(chat_types='private', func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Подтвердить")
def accept(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    # я поменял колбеки, чтобы потом их было проще ловить и фильтровать от других
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ты в лабе⚡", callback_data='labs:add')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ты не в лабе⚡", callback_data='labs:delete')
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать,\n ты в лабе или нет")', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types='private', func=lambda msg: msg.text == " Информация ")
def info(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text="  Мы работаем в сфере создания треков уже 4 года. "
                          "Наша профессиональная команда готова помочь вам с любыми музыкальными трудностями, мы "
                          "обладаем лучшей аппаратурой для выполнений всех задач в сфере музыкального продюсирования. "
                          "Наши услуги дают возможность максимально индивидуализировать продукт под себя.")


@bot.message_handler(chat_types='private', func=lambda msg: msg.text == " Разработчики ")
def devs(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     ' Данный бот был разработан <b>LimeGeeg Corporation™️</b> & '
                     '<b>Cat️</b>, || <b>YouTube: LimeGeeg️</b>',
                     parse_mode='html')


# делаем хендлер для вывода инфы о том кто в "лабе"
@bot.message_handler(chat_types='private', func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Кто в лабе")
def output_labs_data(message: types.Message):
    # перебираем "бд" и записываем тех у кого True
    list_labs_users = []
    for key, value in users.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if value.get("in_lab") is True:
                list_labs_users.append(key)

    result_text = "В лабе:\n"
    for user in list_labs_users:
        user_data = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=user, user_id=user)
        print(user_data)
        result_text += f"{user_data.user.first_name}\n"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=result_text)


# и вот в конец даешь хендлер который впитывает все, но я бы его убрал - бесполезная нагрузка
@bot.message_handler(chat_types='private')
def take_all_message(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'По другим вопросам пишите сюда → @Seapix')


# этот хендлер хоть и есть в документации, но делать так не надо
# @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("labs:"))
def labs_callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # всегда в начале делай answer_callback_query, чтобы пропал значок с часами
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    data = call.data.split(":")[1]
    # вне зависимосте от того жал юзер старт или нет перестрахуемся и еще раз запишем в бд
    users.setdefault(call.from_user.id, {"in_lab": None})
    # если жмакнул кнопку в лабе то делаем True если нет то False
    users[call.from_user.id]["in_lab"] = True if data == "add" else False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: тут у меня ошибка [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JD1-ygte9PaJUJC9O3gu_M5vqpvlc5s3/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: @seapix Ошибка не в коде, у вас где-то запущен еще один экземпляр бота. Либо перезапустите винду либо смените токен